# Google Analytics & Visual Website Optimizer: Critical Issues in Tag Assistant

Tags: javascript, optimization, google-analytics, analytics, tracking

I use Google Analytics on my page, sending data to two web properties. To check the implementation, I use the Google Tag Assistant Chrome plugin.

As soon as I embed the Code to enable the Visual Website Optimizer (a service for heatmaps, A/B Tests, split URL test etc) for my page, the Tag Assistant reports a critical issue for 'Google Analytics UA-XXXXX-X'. Please note that I didn't anonymized anything, it really says 'UA-XXXXX-X'. The description is 'Error: Invalid or missing web property ID', which seems logical as 'UA-XXXXX-X' isn't a valid web property.

In the Google manual it says 'Failing to properly set the Google Analytics web property ID will prevent pageviews from associating to your Analytics website profile.' which is also pretty clear to me, but **can I simply ignore the error the Tag Assistant gives me? Will that corrupt the data send to Google?**

It really leave the impression that the Visual Website Optimizer isn't properly written, could that be true? Or is it just the Tag Assistant thinking its a failed implementation?

Answer (score 0):

can you please check if you are adding some specific prefix in your Visual Website Optimizer test in GA integration settings? I work at with Visual Website optimizer and can help you in this regard. Do mail us on our support email mentioning the account id and the experiment name/id you created.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. No I don't add any prefix. I just mailed your support, so let's see what they say.

Comment: replied to your query on support.